# IF Statements and plotting python

Tags: python, if-statement, plot

I have a variable named hub_wspd and one named hub_wspd_error and so I want to say `if hub_wspd_error is == 0`, then `plot(hub_wspd)`, `if hub_wspd_error is > 0` then don't `plot(hub_wspd)`. How do I do this?

Comment: what you mean by put `is`?

Comment: Can `wspd_err < 0` ever be true?

Answer (score 0):

```
if hub_wspd_error == 0:
    plot(hub_wspd)
elif hub_wspd_error > 0:
    pass
```

Note that the `elif` is not necessary.

Comment: Could also do `if not hub_wspd_error: plot(hub_wspd)`.

Comment: The implication on the question seems to be `if hub_wspd_error < 0` then the whole processing should be skipped. Unless the value can never be negative, it should be tested.